# Show alert onChange of dropdown with Dojo

Tags: forms, dojo, connect, onchange

All,

Simple question here -- new to dojo, can't get it to work.

I'm trying to show an alert when I change the value of a dropdown.  Using dojo.  Here's my code:

This event gets attached when the page loads...

```
dojo.query('#inquiry_type select').connect('onchange', this.Context, 'inquiry_type_onchange');
```

This is the inquiry_type_onchange function...

```
inquiry_type_onchange: function() {
        alert("changed!");
    }
```

My HTML code for the #inqury_type dropdown box...

```
<select name="inquiry_type" id="inquiry_type" class="inquiry_type">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Select Below</option>
        <option value="Place an Order">Place an Order</option>
        <option value="Order Status">Order Status</option>
    </select>
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Is "this.Context" the object where the inquiry_type_onchange function is defined?

Answer (score 1):

try this !
http://jsfiddle.net/4Dxxf/1/

---

```
 dojo.addOnLoad( function() {
     dojo.connect(dojo.byId('#inquiry_type'), "onchange", function(evt) {
                 alert("changed!");
         console.log("option Changed to: "+evt.target.value);
         dojo.stopEvent(evt);
     });
 });
```

---

```
<select name="inquiry_type" id="inquiry_type" class="inquiry_type">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select Below</option>
    <option value="Place an Order">Place an Order</option>
    <option value="Order Status">Order Status</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not quite correct

Change this:

```
dojo.query('#inquiry_type select')
```

to

```
dojo.query('select#inquiry_type')
```

Also some nice examples are here for Dojo 1.6
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/using_query/